# Custom Logic in keycloak registration form

Tags: keycloak, registration, user-registration

I am using Keycloak for managing user registration in my project. I would like to alter the current registration flow, by adding a new field called “registration code” to the form. Then, when the user hits “Submit” I would like keycloak to call my backend endpoint that can verify if the code is correct, mark it as used and return a confirmation to keycloak that the registration can be continued. If the code is not correct, there should be an error saying “Code is incorrect” on the form.

Do you know if that’s possible with keycloak and how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
   <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('code',properties.kcFormGroupErrorClass!)}">
        <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
             <label for="user.attributes.code" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}"> Code</label>
        </div>
        <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
            <input type="text" id="user.attributes.code" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" 
            name="user.attributes.code"
            value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.code']!'')}"/>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Add this to ...keycloak/themes/base/login/register.ftl